# Glassfish 3.1.1 start-local-instance fails with JAXBException

Tags: glassfish

I am setting up a GlassFish cluster following the guide at http://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/glassfish-3-1-clustering-tutorial/. I started from fresh installs of GlassFish 3.1.1. I also have the same architecture as in the guide: two nodes with one instance each. The DAS is on node1.

I've tried starting from scratch several times and am able to create the cluster, nodes and instances without issue. I also have the DAS communicating with node2 via SSH. However, each time when I get to the point where I attempt to start instance2 it fails:

```
$ ./asadmin start-local-instance --node node1 --sync normal instance2
Previous synchronization failed at Feb 23, 2012 2:41:53 PM
Will perform full synchronization.
Removing all cached state for instance instance2.
CLI802 Synchronization failed for directory config, caused by:
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
- with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
Command start-local-instance failed.
```

I spent the day Googling and searching GlassFish's Jira, but couldn't find a solution to this issue. I'd very much appreciate any ideas you have on how to solve this problem.

My operating system is CentOS 5.7 and my Java version is 1.6.0_20

Unfortunately my instance directory is empty, I'm assuming because it never started. So there is no log file. I set AS_DEBUG=true but it gives no stack trace. The last debug lines before the error are

```
Removing all cached state for instance instance2.
Removing: /usr/local/glassfish3_1_1/glassfish/nodes/blade-50/instance2/config
Removing: /usr/local/glassfish3_1_1/glassfish/nodes/blade-50/instance2/applications
Removing: /usr/local/glassfish3_1_1/glassfish/nodes/blade-50/instance2/generated
Removing: /usr/local/glassfish3_1_1/glassfish/nodes/blade-50/instance2/lib
Removing: /usr/local/glassfish3_1_1/glassfish/nodes/blade-50/instance2/docroot
Got exception: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
```

Comment: What do the log files say? can you post in the error?

Comment: Also, not sure if it has anything to do with it (haven't set up a cluster before) but the biggest problem I have with glassfish is it trying to us the same port's somewhere

Comment: How do you know it's a port issue. Can you post the error?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no log file. I added the last bit of debug output (see above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acting on a [tip from a user in the Glassfish forum](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/start-local-instance-fails-jaxbexception), I learned that Java 1.6.0_20 is an older release of Java that is not supported by Glassfish 3.1.1. I worked with a sysadmin to get Java 1.6.0_31 installed on both nodes of the cluster and that did the trick--both instances start up without errors.